# Use form tag in web app or not?

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile to develop my web apps.
On a dialog I want to use a number field.
Is it always necessary to wrap this input in form?

```
<form>
<label for="text-input">Input:</label>
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" name="text-input" id="text-input" value="" maxlength="4" />
</form>
```

The documentation gives an example with and another example without form. So I want to know weather it is recommended or not. And if I have to use a form, is it necessary to give that tag an id, an action and a method attribute?
My use case is that I only want to offer the number field and handle the content via JavaScript. I don't want to send the form data to any other web page or php script or like that.

Comment: No, form tags are not required. I use them anyway, but that's just personal preference. Here's a discussion on the topic: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-Are-HTML-FORM-Tags-Required-To-Display-Form-Input-Controls-.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly by the html4 and html5 specs, form tags are not required to use form controls for a user interface.

From the html4 spec:

> The elements used to create controls generally appear inside a FORM element, but may also appear outside of a FORM element declaration when they are used to build user interfaces.

the html5 version of it is a little more complicated and can be found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html51-20121217/forms.html#association-of-controls-and-forms

What i took from that as far as form controls needing a parent form is that a form control doesn't *have* to be associated to a form, which would mean it doesn't have to be nested in one (if it were nested in a form, it would be associated to that form).

---

I still prefer to use form tags anyway, that way I can take advantage of the fact that pressing enter on an input will submit it without having to do additional coding.